# Get all text from page

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

I need to get all visible text from the page (and to compare it later with json file for localisation testing). Is there an easy way to do this with Protractor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('html').getText().then(function(text) {console.log(text)});`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Google before asking questions. But an answer to your question is that you don't need any thirdparty apps for this. It's already possible with HTML and Javascript as is.

You can read more here: [link to W3](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: I know I don't need Protractor for this but I'm using it already and I was looking for some easy way to grab all visible text with webdriver within my scripts. To get text from one object is easy, I was looking for a way to grab everything from the page. Sorry if I was not clear from start.